# Simple tray icon application using pygtk

Tags: python, pygtk, trayicon, tray

I'm writing a webmail checker in python and I want it to just sit on the tray icon and warn me when there is a new email. Could anyone point me in the right direction as far as the gtk code?

I already coded the bits necessary to check for new email but it's CLI right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use a gtk.StatusIcon to actually display the icon. [Here are the docs](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkstatusicon.html). If you're just getting started with gui programming you might want to work though a bit of the [pygtk tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

This http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkstatusicon.html should get you going.